# Is the spacetime interval a tensor?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry

Tensors are objects that are invarient under a change of basis representation and whose coordinates change predictably. The spacetime interval is invarient under a change of coordinate representation caused by a change in frame of reference and the coordinates describing it change predictably with the Lorentz transformations.

My question is: Do we consider the spacetime interval to be a tensor, or a tensor-like object in any way mathematically? Or is this similarity something different and I am connecting the wrong dots?

Comment: The space-time interval $ds^2=g_{ij} du^{i}du^{j}$  is defined by the metric tensor - the metric tensor defines the inner product on the tangent space. And $ds^{2}$ is not a tensor - it's a $2-$form - it's ordinary multiplication between $du^{i}$ and $du^{j}$. The length of an infinitesimal tangent vector is $ds$, and the arc length of a curve would be $s=\int^{t_1}_{t_0} \sqrt { g_{ij} \frac {du^{i}}{dt} \frac{du^{j}}{dt}} dt$ - which would be a scalar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is technically yes, as has been lined out, but in regards to the second part of the question the answer is an emphatic **NO**. It should never be treated as a tensor because that only works in flat space and will only lead to future misunderstandings and lots of wasted time.

To give a longer answer: The great thing about most tensors in special relativity is that they turn into similar tensors in general relativity because they are local and locally space-time still looks like Minkowski space. The reason this does not work with the space-time interval is that it is actually non-local. Here local means that it should only depend on what happens in a small neighborhood around the single point you are considering. If you consider the space-time distance between two points it kind of depends on two different points as well as on everything that happens in between.

What you should think about the space-time interval instead is as the length of a curve taken in a specific invariant way. It depends on the curve taken and thus on the end-points and everything inbetween. It just so happens in flat Minkowski-space that for any pair of points there is an obvious curve between two points in the form of a straight line.

Answer (score 10):

Edit: I no longer agree with my answer, and I think it would be appropriate to accept one of the other answers. Depending on what you mean by the spacetime interval, it's either a non-local, non-tensorial thing (if we're talking about $\Delta s$), or a 2-form that happens to be preserved by Lorentz transformations (if we're talking about $ds^2$).

The spacetime interval is Lorentz invariant. That is, it is a scalar. A scalar is a particular case of a tensor. One could call it a (0,0)-tensor (as in zero covariant and zero contravariant indices).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does it's invarience under Lorentz transformations make it a tensor or is it a tensor simply because it is a scalar and all scalars are tensors by definition?. And as a follow up if you don't mind, when we transform basis vectors describing tensors by operating on them with a transformation matrix, is this mathematically what we are doing when we change coordinate representations of events in spacetime (with the Lorentz transformations) during frame of reference changes?

Comment: Tensors are things that transform under Lorentz transformations (or more general coordinate transformations, depending on the context) in a definite way. Specifically, one transforms a tensor by contracting its indices with those of Lorentz transformation tensors. A scalar is a tensor because it transforms in this definite way. But a scalar has no indices so nothing happens to it when you Lorentz transform it.

Comment: As for your second question, if I am reading it correctly the answer is yes.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: The spacetime interval is not a scalar, it is a map from vectors to scalars.

Comment: @mmeent I guess I am confused then. The definitions of the spacetime interval I have seen make it manifestly a scalar. To be clear, I am talking about the thing one usually writes as $ds$. It seems like what you are talking about is the metric tensor or something like it.

Comment: @d_b The thing people write as $ds^2$ *is* the metric tensor!

Comment: I see. You are right. I was getting objects and their components confused. I'll fix my answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

The spacetime interval is a bilinear map that takes two (relative position) 4-vectors and produces a scalar. This means that is a rank 2 tensor (more specifically type $(0,2)$). In most basic special relativity context, the two 4-vectors are taken to be two copies of the same position 4-vector, but this does not change the mathematical nature of the underlying object.

Comment: I agree with @d_b when he says that you are talking about the metric tensor. The spacetime interval is a single real number and any inertial observer agrees on its value. This makes it a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, yes, because the spacetime interval is a Lorentz scalar. But be aware that many people use the word "tensor" to refer to what is more properly called a tensor *field* defined on a manifold. These people would not consider the spacetime interval between two points in Minkowski spacetime to be a tensor (although they would consider the local infinitesimal version - the metric - to be one).